# How to reset a RxJs stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following RxJs for a autocomplete:

```
this.persons = this.searchField.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(q => q.length >= 3),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(q => {
        this.isSearching = true;
        return this.service.findPerson(q).pipe(catchError(e => this.onSearchError(e)));
    }),
    map(res => {
        this.isSearching = false;
        return res.body;
   })
);
```

That works great except for one thing: the persons Observable is not reset when the search field is cleared. Is there a nice way how I can achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by reset?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai the Observable should emit an empty value so that the result list is not displayed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just change the order of operators and instead of `filter` return `EMPTY` inside `switchMap` (or eventually eg. `of(null)` depending on how you want  to clear your autocomplete.

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

...

this.searchField.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(q => {
        if (q.length >= 3) {
            this.isSearching = true;
            return this.service.findPerson(q).pipe(catchError(e => this.onSearchError(e)));
        } else {
            this.isSearching = false;
            return EMPTY; // or `of(...)` with some value so you know that the autocomplete should be cleared.
        }
    }),
    map(res => {
        this.isSearching = false;
        return res.body;
    });
```

Comment: this could throw an error at res.body, since res would now be empty/string and you are mapping it to get a value as an object ?

Comment: `map` won't throw exception because `EMPTY` doesn't emit any value. That's also why I left the comment there because it depends on OP logic. `3` is hardcoded because I doubt you want to change it on fly as a value from a different Observable.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But I had to use `of({ body: [] })` instead of `EMPTY`.